# SFTP client that uses Mosh?

Tags: windows, sftp

I recently discovered [Mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) which is great for flaky connections but it's only for a terminal session apparently. I use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)'s [keep up-to-date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) feature which is where I could *really* use Mosh, but unfortunately WinSCP [doesn't yet support Mosh](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13973), and it seems unlikely it will.

Is there a similar SFTP client but one that uses Mosh instead of regular SSH?

It should work on Windows.

Comment: Mosh simply doesn't work that way. There isn't any ability to exchange information other than the shell screen and keystrokes. So, no, you won't find this. Slowly they may add some of ssh's features back into mosh, and this could be possible. But not yet.